# How to use Immersive Reader in Sway?

Tags: office-sway

Some of Microsoft tools have Immersive Reader mode, where it changes the text appearance and can read aloud the words to people with learning difficulties.

Is there a way to activate this within a Sway presentation? I'm using Microsoft Teams to deliver the Sway presentations to people.